# How to send/receive SMS in Zoiper with a Twilio number?

Tags: twilio, sip, voip, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I have a Twilio mobile number that has both voice and SMS functionality. I am able to make and receive calls in Zoiper, but I don't know how to set it up so I can also send/receive SMS. There are no guides on how to do this. How do I set this up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio doesn't support SMS over SIP, only via [the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) (outbound) and [webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml) (inbound). Twilio doesn't support SMS via `SIP SIMPLE` (as the [Zoiper docs mention](https://www.zoiper.com/en/support/answer/for/linux/61/Chat_and_Presence)) so you cannot directly set up sending and receiving SMS messages via Twilio through Zoiper.